# One Dimensional Representations of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am currently trying to find the irreducible one dimensional representations for the subgroup $H$ of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ consisting of the upper triangular matrices.
I know the number of irreducible one dimensional representations is equal to the order of the abelianization of the group, so that's how I began.
I found the commutator subgroup of H to be the upper triangular matrices with 1's in each entry of the diagonal. It is clear this group has $p^3$ elements. I also calculated $H$ to have $(p-1)(p^2-p)(p^3-p^2)$ elements; this means that the abelianization of $H$ has $$\frac{(p-1)(p^2-p)(p^3-p^2)}{p^3}=(p-1)^3$$ elements. I was wondering if there's anymore information I can extrapolate from this, i.e., what do these $(p-1)^3$ representations actually look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that any element of $H$ may be written as a diagonal matrix (with non-zero entries on the diagonal) times an element of the commutator subgroup $H'$. If we let $D$ denote the subgroup of diagonal matrices, then since $D \cap H' = 1$, this gives a semidirect product decomposition $H = H' \rtimes D$. The abelianization can then be identified as $H/H' \cong D$. Since any one-dimensional representation $\phi$ of $H$ has  $H'$ in its kernel, $\phi$ is determined by its restriction to $D$. Thus the problem is reduced to identifying the one-dimensional representations of $D \cong \mathbb (F_p^*)^3$.